# Как можно добавить горизонтальный эффект?

Tags: jquery

Как можно добавить горизонтальный переходный эффект? Например, Basic Example [такой](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).show();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
padding: 20px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 14px;        
}
ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
font-family: tahoma;
}
li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
font-family: tahoma;
}
.tabs-menu {
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.tabs-menu li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
}

.tabs-menu li.current {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    z-index: 5;
}

.tabs-menu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.tabs-menu .current a {
    color: #2e7da3;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.tab-content {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}

#tab-1 {
 display: block;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то типа такого https://jsfiddle.net/57sn3k5n/embedded/result/

```js
    var state = 1,
      tabWidth = 400,
      offset = 0;

    $('#prev').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var changeState = function(orientation) {
      if (orientation == 'next' && state < $('.tabs-outer .tab').length) {
        $('.tabs-outer').css({
          'transform': 'translateX(-' + (offset + tabWidth) + 'px)'
        })
        offset = offset + tabWidth;
        state++
      } else if (orientation == 'prev' && state > 1) {
        $('.tabs-outer').css({
          'transform': 'translateX(-' + (offset - tabWidth) + 'px)'
        })
        offset = offset - tabWidth;
        state--
      }
      $('.tabs-outer .tab').removeClass('active');
      $('.tab-list li').removeClass('active');
      $('.tabs-outer .tab' + state).addClass('active');
      $('.tab-list .li' + state).addClass('active');
    }
    $('.buttons button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var orientation = $(this).attr('id');
      changeState(orientation);

      if (state == 1) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $('#prev').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      if (state == $('.tabs-outer .tab').length - 1 || state == $('.tabs-outer .tab').length) {
        if (state == $('.tabs-outer .tab').length) {
          $('#next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
          $('#next').text('next').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        $('#next').text('finish');
      } else {
        $('#next').text('next').removeAttr('disabled');
      }

    })
```

```css
.tab-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.tab-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #cacaca;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tab-list li.active {
  background: red;
}
.tabs-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
.tabs-outer {
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
  width: 1200px;
  /* summ of 3 tabs   */
}
.tabs-outer .tab {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-list">
  <li class="active li1">tab1</li>
  <li class="li2">tab2</li>
  <li class="li3">tab3</li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <div class="tabs-outer">
    <div class="tab tab1 active">111Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="tab tab2">222Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="tab tab3">333Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="prev">prev</button>
  <button id="next">next</button>
</div>
```

На скорую руку. Надеюсь будет полезным

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!

Comment: всегда рад помочь :)